# Can someone please tell where am I wrong?

Tags: tree

`findrightsiblings` takes a node reference and returns its right sibling i.e. the leftmost node at its level on its right. It throws a null pointer exception. Please help.

```
public static Node find(Node root, int k) {
    if (root == null)
        return null;

    if (k == 0)
        return root;

    Node m = find(root.left, k - 1);

    if (m == null)
        m = find(root.right, k - 1);

    return m;
}

public static Node findRightSibling(Node node) {
    Node y = node.parent;
    int count = 1;

    while (true) {
        if (y.right != null) {
            Node js = find(y.right, count - 1);

            if (js != null)
                return js;
        }

        y = y.parent;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a problem statement ? Please paste it here and also the full code if possible

Comment: This is a problem from gfg, and i cudnt find what wrong in my soln    https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boundary-traversal-of-binary-tree/

Comment: If possible, please paste your full code. However, you are referencing node.parent and y=y.parent. What happens when it is a root node and y becomes null. Did you check that possibility ?

Comment: Shall I add it as an answer ?

Comment: yes u can add it, i will upvote